# keeping precise alignment during cube duplication?

Tags: duplicate

I used the Object-> Duplicate Objects to get two cubes, but then when the mouse cursor is moved, the duplicate cube does not stay in alignment.  How can I snap the copied cube into perfect alignment with the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click. That will not cancel the duplication, just the subsequent move, so the copy will be dropped exactly in place.

If you want to **move** the copied object in alignment to some axis with respect to the original, (having chosen your Transform Orientation,) then the shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>  will constrain the movement of the copy without a further operation.

Those shortcuts can be followed immediately by a number, to move along the axis by a specified distance.

If, for example, you wanted the movement directions to align to the object-axes of the original, you would set the Transform Orientation to 'Local'.

Comment: Appreciate your response, but unfortunately the cube was already placed and the project underway.  I had hoped at the end to just go back and snap the new cube into place with the original one.

Comment: That should still be fine, please illustrate your case, and/or share on https://blend-exchange.com/